# LDAP - .NET DirectoryEntry with StartTLS

Tags: .net, vb.net, ldap

we have an AD Domain which uses with LDAP uncrypted and crypted via StartTLS on port 398. Our Admins changed our DCs within the last weeks so that both techniques are actually running. I tested it via:

```
openssl s_client -debug -connect mydomain.company:389 -starttls ldap -showcert
```

I got a result with a valid (!) certificate.

We want use StartTLS and not LDAPS because LDAPS is retired.

Our software is currently using the .NET (4.5.2) Class DirectoryEntry/DirectorySearcher and connect to LDAP Domain at port 398 with "AuthenticationTypes.Secure". Our code works with no errors - But the connection is uncrypted because the DirectoryEntry-Class is not using StartTLS - I can see it via Wireshark.

I tried "AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer" but this seems only working for the retired LDAPS on port 636.

Heres a sample code which works without StartTLS on port 398:

```
      Using objDirectorySearcher As New DirectorySearcher

        Using objSearchEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mydomain.local:389", mstrUsername, mstrPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)

          objDirectorySearcher.SearchRoot = objSearchEntry
          objDirectorySearcher.Filter = String.Format(mstrLDAPFilterUser, strUsername)
          objDirectorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree

          objDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(...)


          Dim objSearchResult As SearchResult = objDirectorySearcher.FindOne()
          ...
```

So is it possible to get the DirectorySearcher to work with LDAP StartTLS? Does anybody using this?

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer? We are in the same situation...

Comment: Hey, yes but it was a huge of work... We didn't use the DirectorySearcher - instead we are using the LdapConnection. For StartTLS you should use "LDAPConnection.SessionOptions.StartTransportLayerSecurity(null)"

Comment: Aw, that's what I feared... :( If you have time, you can add this as an accepted answer (yes, you can answer your own question), so it will be easier for future fellow devs to find this useful piece of information. Anyway, thank you for getting back to me!